# Prove on $n$ people there are two such that among the $n-2$ there are at least $\lfloor n/2\rfloor-1$, either all knowing or not knowing the two.

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

> There are $n$ people at a party. Prove there are two of them such that of the remaining $n − 2$ people there are at least $\lfloor n/2\rfloor − 1$ of them each of whom knows both or else knows neither of the two.

I’m aware this question is already asked on here; however, I’m trying to avoid looking at solutions. I will sketch my attempts below. I believe I’m at a dead end. If someone would be willing to give hints or help me I would appreciate it.

My attempt:

If we can prove it for an even $n$ then it should be true for $n+1$ on account of the floor. Say then you have $2n$ people.

There are $\binom{2n}{2}$ pairs of people in this group.

For a fixed person $k$ with number of friends $d_k$, there are $\binom{d_k}{2}+\binom{2n-1-d_k}{2}$ pairs relative to which $k$ is known to both or not known to both in the pair; we will call this the set of agreeements on $k$. Let $A$ be the set of agreements across all $k \in [2n]$.

I won’t bother proving the algebra; however, I am relative certain I haven’t made a mistake writing that

$$|A| = \sum_k \binom{d_k}{2}+\binom{2n-1-d_k}{2} \ge 2n\bigg(\binom{n}{2}+\binom{n-1}{2}\bigg)= n(2n^2-4n+2).$$

Then we know $\frac{|A|}{|\binom{[2n]}{2}|}\ge \frac{(2n-1)(n-2)+n}{(2n-1)} =n-2+\frac{n}{2n-1} $, implying that some pair must have $n-1$ people on which they agree.

However, at this point I am stuck. This pair could agree on $n-1$ people, but there is no guarantee that they are all known or unknown to the pair. Have I read the problem wrong in that I just need to find $n-1$ from the $2n$ that agree on two of the vertices or can this be taken further to two vertices which dominate or fail to dominate all $n-1$ vertices?

Comment: You've read the problem wrong. It's just that the pair either both know or neither knows that person. It's not that the pair must either know or not know ALL of the other n/2 - 1 people. Your solutions works (assuming the inequality holds).

Comment: @CalvinLin I see. Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a pair $(u,v)$ of vertices, we call $w$ *unsuitable* if it is connected to exactly one of $u$ and $v$. We want to find a pair with as few unsuitable vertices as possible. Let $T$ be the minimal number of unsuitable vertices generated by a pair $(u,v)$. Of course, it suffices to solve the prolem for even $n$ and we want to prove that $T\leqslant \frac{n}{2}-1$.

We will double-count triples $(u,v;w)$ where $w$ is unsuitable for $(u,v)$. On one hand, as per the definition of $T$, we have at least $T\binom{n}{2}$such triples. On the other hand, a vertex $w$ of degree $d$ lies in exactly $d\cdot (n-1-d)$ such triples (more specifically, in the last position), hence $$\sum_v\deg v(n-1-\deg v)\geqslant T\binom{n}{2}\implies2E(n-1)\geqslant T\binom{n}{2}+\sum_v(\deg v)^2,$$where $E$ denotes the number of edges in our graph. By Cauchy-Schwarz, we further have $$2E(n-1)\geqslant T\binom{n}{2}+\sum_v(\deg v)^2\geqslant T\binom{n}{2}+\frac{4E^2}{n}.$$Rearranging and applying the am-gm inequality, we finally get $$T\binom{n}{2}\frac{n}{4}\leqslant E\left(\binom{n}{2}-E\right)\leqslant\frac{1}{4}\binom{n}{2}^2\implies T\leqslant\frac{n-1}{2}.$$But since $T$ is an integer, it follows that $T\leqslant \lfloor\frac{n-1}{2}\rfloor=\frac{n}{2}-1$ and we are done.

Comment: -1 OP has indicated that they would like help with completing their proof (which may or may not be possible), as opposed to knowing the solution.

Comment: Where did OP say that? They said "If someone would be willing to give hints or help me I would appreciate it." I just helped them. And even so, is this a reason for a -1?